# Speak to a device using TCP/IP

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I try to open a TCP stream to speak to a device with a cocoa app.
I searched the web and found that there is some possibilities to do that but i'm a little bit stuck.

I decided to use the NSStream way (because it's referenced in cocoa-touch, will be usefull if i want to port my app to iPhone i presume), so here is my code:

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (IBAction)connect:(id)sender {

    [NSStream getStreamsToHost:"192.168.1.4" port:23 inputStream:&inputStream outputStream:&outputStream];

    [inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [outputStream setDelegate:self];

    [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [inputStream open];
    [outputStream open];
}

// Both streams call this when events happen
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
    if (aStream == inputStream) {
        [self handleInputStreamEvent:eventCode];
    } else if (aStream == outputStream) {
        [self handleOutputStreamEvent:eventCode];
    }
}

- (void)handleInputStreamEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
    switch (eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:[self readBytes];
            break;
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            // Do Something
            break;
        default:
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            NSLog(@"An error occurred on the input stream.");
            break;
    }

}
```

So, when I click on my connect button, it is supposed to open the stream to my host and make my 2 objects (inputstream and outputstream)

The first step I would like to reach is to have the inputStream in a NSTextView and know if the host has been reached or not... but i'm still stuck :(

If someone can light my way, it would be nice! I'm new on Stack Overflow and I'll be glad to help the community on somethings that i know much! :)

---

I updated my code and it seems that the light is coming, slowly but it's coming :)
I made a stream to a telnet server. I got the "hello" in a texview.
Now, I would like to send the user & password to be able to send commands to the server, but here is my "send user & pass" button code:

```
- (IBAction)sendusername:(id)sender {

    NSString * usernameMsg  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user @", [usernameField stringValue]];
    NSData * usertosend = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[usernameMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [outputStream write:[usertosend bytes] maxLength:[usertosend length]];

}
```

Follow my searchs, the server should respond me a thing like "user +ok" but nothing...
2 stranges things:
- If I open the socket to a FTP server of SSH server, I've always the "hello" response without problem. But in telnet, 90% of connections respond me a strange hello like this: "ÿýÿýÿûÿû", why?

- When I send the user, nothing happen, only an unrocognized event from the handleEvent...

Comment: What happens when you do this? And have you verified that 192.168.1.4 (why are you hard-coding that?) is listening on port 23?

Comment: 192.168.1.4 is listening on port 23 (telnet). I can reach it with the terminal. I hard-coded the address to be sure that the error does not come from the entry. Nothing happen when I do this, i though that I'll see something in the log, but nothing :/

Comment: Still in the black, can't find the good configuration for NSStream and can't talk/have a response from the server :(

Comment: Not sure why [NSStream getStreamsToHost: inputStream: outputStream:] does not work here.
Consider using [NSNetService getInputStream: outputStream:] if applicable.

Comment: The "ÿýÿýÿûÿû" is Telnet IAC sequences. Read RFC 854 (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc854) for details on what these are and how to handle them. (You can safely ignore most of them.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you explain me how to translate this "ÿýÿýÿûÿû" ? I don't understand :/

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to look at https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/, a nice Objective-C wrapper for BSD sockets. It allows you to handle the send-receive interactions on the event loop in nice and clean callback manner (it even handles custom "message terminating" symbols for you allowing to concentrate more on actual packet handling rather then on combining and splitting the stuff you receive from wire).